# Adjust position calculated by |-

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this snippet, which works fine:

```
\coordinate(foo) at (start |- something.south);
```

However, I want to add some value onto the y of `something.south` prior to calculating the `|-`. I've tried every combination of syntax I could think of, including this one I thought should work:

```
\coordinate(foo) at (start |- something.south+(0,1mm));
```

However, this gives an error:

```
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
```

How can I adjust a point prior to applying the `|-` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are three ways to accomplish this, only the last one requires the `calc` library. This list is not exhaustive.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[x=0.5mm,local bounding box=L]%
    \coordinate(start) at (0,0);
    \coordinate(end) at (230, 0);
    \node (something) at (50,3) {something};
    \coordinate(foo) at ([yshift=1mm]something.south-|start); 
    \draw[thick,->] (start) -- (foo);
  \end{scope}
  \node[above] at (L.north){with \texttt{yshift}};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,x=0.5mm,local bounding box=M]%
    \coordinate(start) at (0,0);
    \coordinate(end) at (230, 0);
    \node (something) at (50,3) {something};
    \path (something.south-|start) + (0,1mm) coordinate(foo); 
    \draw[thick,->] (start) -- (foo);
  \end{scope}
  \node[above] at (M.north){with \texttt{path}};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm,x=0.5mm,local bounding box=R]%
    \coordinate(start) at (0,0);
    \coordinate(end) at (230, 0);
    \node (something) at (50,3) {something};
    \coordinate(foo) at ($(something.south-|start)+(0,1mm)$); 
    \draw[thick,->] (start) -- (foo);
  \end{scope}
  \node[above] at (R.north){with \texttt{calc}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]